# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require. How can I fix this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to export some functions from my database.js file and require them into the other file login.js, which is in the same folder. I tried also to declare the require globally and in a function, both ways did not work. I am using node.js/express.js.

**DATABASE.JS**

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'minigames',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});
    
function connected(){
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected...");
    })
}

function select(attribute){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let sql = `SELECT ${attribute} FROM player`;
        connection.query(sql, (err, result, field) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))));
        })
    })
}

async function query(attribute) {
    return await select(attribute);
}


module.exports = {connection, connected, select, query};
```

**LOGIN.JS**

```
let userList = [];
function checkLogin(){
    const database = require('./database');
    let userListPromise = database.query('username, password');
    userListPromise
    .then()
    .then((values) =>{
        let i = 0;
        while(values[i] != null){
            userList.push(values[i]);
            i++;
        }
        console.log("list filled");
        console.log(userList);
    })
}
checkLogin();
```

Comment: You can confirm you're using NodeJS, right (and not frontend JavaScript)? Does your `package.json` file contain `"type": "module"`?

Comment: Yes, If I am doing that I am getting this error "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension."

Comment: The solution is simple. Either remove `"type": "module"` from your `package.json`, or rename your file to `fileName.cjs` instead of `fileName.js`.